# Criar form e gridView dinamicamente com VB6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic-6, ssis

Eu preciso criar um formulario dinamicamente pelo codigo e adicionar um gridView e um botao a esse formulario, alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja essa referência, How To Dynamically Add Controls to a Form with Visual Basic 6.0 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190670 .

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara! consegui fazer oque eu precisava aqui obrigado.